# Why executable is found

Tags: node.js, command-line, path, binary, npm

I do `npm install grunt -g` and the folder is created `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli`. In my path variable only the `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm` part is added. How then when I write `grunt` in the command line the grunt executable inside `\grunt-cli` folder is found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you install `grunt-cli`, npm creates a file `grunt` (and `grunt.cmd`) inside `C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm` so directly in your the folder in your path

If you look into this file you can see it calls `node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt`